# Calling function in an unknown class for libraries

Tags: c++, lua

I have a few Libraries defined in C++ source code. My problem is whenever a library is removed or a new one is added, something has to call the libraries "Initialize" function.

An example would be: A class for Network sockets called CLuaNet which has a function called CLuaNet::Initialize(*State);. How do I call this function in my project since I cannot predict the library name? If possible I would like this "linking" to be done at compile time, something like a macro.

Whenever a new instance of a Lua environment is opened, every library's initialize function has to be called with an the Lua state as argument.

The project runs on different architectures (X86/X64/ARMv6/ARMv7) and operating systems, making compiled libraries for every possible platform and OS combination is not feasible (Windows - DLL, Linux - SO, etc..). This is intended to be a server application.

**EDIT:** I am not using DLLs or SOs - everything is compiled into one executable for portability.

> Note: I dont have alot of experience in project design/managment. Id
>   like to hear opinions and tips about my approach on this.

Comment: You can leverage the library's DLL main or dylib initialize routines, which gets called automatically when the library is loaded or unloaded. For Windows OS you can use DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH and macOS/*nix there are corresponding init methods you can use. There you can run the init code.

Comment: @kvr I think my question was a little mit misleading. Im not using DLLs for portability reasons. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The normal mechanism for coping with name finding, is to create another well named function which returns sufficient meta data to allow you to call it.

```
 extern "C" DLLEXPORT const MetaInfo & InfoFunction() 
 {
     static MetaInfo luaNet(
               CLuaNet::Initialize,
               CLuaNet::Finalize,
               CLuaNet::SomethingElse );
     return luaNet; // Give main application information on how to call me

 }
```

Where `DLLEXPORT` declares a function to be exported from the DLL/shared object.

`MetaInfo` is compiled into the DLL/shared object and has a set of well-defined slots which perform useful functions.

e.g.

```
struct MetaInfo {
     int (*initializeFunction)( lua_State * L );
     int (*closeFunction)( lua_State * L );
     int (*utilityFunction)( lua_State* L );
     MetaInfo( int (*)(lua_State *) init,
               int (*)( lua_State*) fini,
               int (*)( lua_State*) other ) :
              initializeFunction( init),
              closeFunction( fini ),
              utilityFunction( other ) {}

};
```

Comment: Interesting, I have never heard of MetaInfo in C/C++. The string DLLEXPORT hints that this is to be used within a DLL, correct? I edited my question to clarify that im not using external binaries. If im incorrect, what would the receiving part for this look like? Thanks.